# Bootloader Erased from MRAM after Running

Tags: memory, linker, bootloader, boot, u-boot

I am trying to burn the U-boot bootloader in MRAM on my board so that it is able to boot-up on a restart without having to use a serial debugger. I am loading the file using GRMON with the flag -wprot to temporarily enable flash writes to MRAM. The bootloader seems to load into MRAM correctly and then when I run "go 0" the U-boot prompts showup correctly in the serial output. After loading u-boot, there is data stored at 0x00000000 (81882fe0), but when I stop execution and recheck the memory, it seems to be erased. MRAM writes should stick and permanently change the contents of MRAM, so I'm not sure why the bootloader is being erased? Here's an image of what's occurring: [image]

Comment: Your misuse of jargon is confusing.  *"I am trying to burn ..."* -- What chemical reaction is involved when writing to MRAM?  Writing to optical discs does employ a chemical reaction, so "burn" in that case is appropriate.  Using "burn" for other forms of writing displays ignorance.  *"...flash writes to MRAM"* -- MRAM is not "flash", so what is this supposed to mean?  *"Here's an image of what's occurring..."* -- Displaying just one word is not very informative.  FYI U-Boot typically relocates itself to high memory.  Could memory location `0` then be written (*"erased"*) for some reason?

Comment: Your question is not solvable without more information: Which board, which architecture, which version of U-Boot are you referring to?